# React Native - APK generation failed

Tags: react-native, mobx

guys.
I`m work on RN app.
In the dev process everything work fine, the app launched at my device, but when i tried generate APK, i`ll stuck with next error message:

> SyntaxError D:/Sites/work/CECI/src/stores/AppStore.js: Unexpected
>   token (12:4)
>
> :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 43.156 secs
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
>
>   > Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Beginning of AppStore.js:

```
import {action, computed, observable, toJS} from 'mobx';
import {forEach, size, flatMap, sortBy, last} from 'lodash';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import store from 'rn-object-store';
import moment from 'moment';


const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();

class AppStore {
    @observable user = null;
    @observable auth = {
        authUser:  null,
        authError: null,
        loggedIn:  null
    };
    @observable userRef = null;
    @observable decisionsRef = null;
    @observable quizzesRef = null;
    @observable _decisions = {};
    @observable _quizzes = {};
    @observable activeQuestion = 0;
    @observable activeQuiz = null;
    @observable activeDecision = null;
    @observable reports = {};
```

So if i understand right row with issue is  `@observable user = null;`
What can be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cd android && ./gradlew clean

Comment: not help 
why stackoverflow gives this post green check icon ?!